# React Native library that provide OAuth2 authentification with PKCE

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, pkce

I'm developping my first native application with [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/). This app will be an extension of a website that I already made and that already provide OAuth 2.0 authorization (= the backend is ready).

I what that my React Native App can connect the user to the website using Oauth2 authentification (login and password first, and then remember with an Auth Code).

I think that the best way to identify the user is to provide an [Authorization Code Flow](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/) whith [Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://oauth.net/2/pkce/) extension.

This is the recommandation of [OAuth 2.0 for for Mobile and Native Apps](https://oauth.net/2/native-apps/).

How can I implement that in React Native ? I already made a lot of research and found a lot of articles or tutorials (but all deprecated or not complete).. The best for me would be to reuse an existing code  or a javascript library (not deprecated).

Thank you for your help.